FBX Animation not playing ThreeJS
I have a threejs scene with a FBX model found here. I downloaded the model by itself in a T-pose position. I also downloaded a falling animation from the same site here.
I have successfully imported the model:
// MODEL
const loader = new FBXLoader()
loader.load('resources/script/model/goblin_d_shareyko.fbx', (fbx) => {
    
    fbx.scale.setScalar(0.02)
    fbx.position.y = -2
    
    
    const anim = new FBXLoader()
    anim.load('resources/script/model/Falling.fbx', (anim) => {
        mixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(fbx)
        const idle = mixer.clipAction(anim.animations[0])
        idle.play()
    })
    scene.add(fbx)
})

And while the model loads just fine, and apparently so does the animation since there are no errors showing in my browser console, the model remains in a T-Pose and the animation does not play.
I added mixer.update() to my main animate function, and when I do that, the model shows the character falling (static), rather in a T-Pose, but does not animate.
What am I missing so I can have a fluid animation of the model?

Just under a few minutes after posted I figured it out. I needed to change the mixer.update() call to mixer.update(elapsedTime * 0.0001) using a clock.
